# How to convert cbr to pdf?

Tags: 12.04, pdf, calibre

I have a comic strip book in cbr (Calibre?) format. How can I convert it to pdf in my Ubuntu 12.04? I tried to install calibre hoping that it is able to do so. But it seems to be buggy and does not show up. Appreciate your hints to do the conversion.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the CBR (and CBZ) formats are not Calibre specific.  They are "Comic Book Rar" and "Comic Book Zip" formats respectively.

Answer (score 15):

Found a nifty way to do this.
Programs that you might need are `rar` and `imagemagick`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rar imagemagick
```

Next, rename all the files extension that you want to convert, from `*.cbr` to `*.rar`.

Example: comic.cbr -->  comic.rar

Next, use `rar` and extract all the .rar files. You should get .jpg files as output.

Next, use `imagemagick` to covert all into one. Make sure you are in that directory.

Example use in terminal:

```
convert *.jpg comic.pdf
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately **`convert`** and **`calibre`** changes the image quality/resolution, which is very important to CBR and CBZ, so to have **no loss of quality**, practically using  the original `jpg` that is inside the CBR(CBZ) files you need to use `img2pdf`, I use this commands:

First need to install this:

```
sudo apt install img2pdf p7zip-full
```

1) This to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

```
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
```

2) This to concatenate the `pdf`pages into one:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

[I made this batch files](https://github.com/eduardflorinescu/cbr2pdf)

### **./cbr2pdf.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd` 
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
cp "$1" "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
7z e "$1" 
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "$JPEGS/combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf"
```

### cat cbz2pdf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd` 
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
unzip -j "$1" -d "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "$JPEGS/combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf"
```

To convert all `cbr` and `cbz` in folder and subfolders:

```
tree -fai . | grep -P "cbr$" | xargs -L1 -I{} ./cbr2pdf.sh {}
```

and

```
tree -fai . | grep -P "cbz$" | xargs -L1 -I{} ./cbz2pdf.sh {}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and calibre did the job perfectly for me. 
Your problem is installing calibre. If I'm not wrong I managed to install it
 by upgrading python

Answer (score 3):

Just found another command line tools that works great
http://sharedby.jauco.nl/cbr2pdf

you can install in /usr/bin

I requires some packages that you can install with

> sudo apt-get install pdftk sam2p unrar unzip

Then just launch

> cbr2pdf [file.cbr]

To have file.pdf on the same directoy

Answer (score 1):

There is a script that should do cbr2pdf conversion, though I didn't try it. Link is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cbr2pdf/